# How to implement nested search in a list

Tags: c#, mvvm

I'm trying to solve a problem where I need to filter a list which hold my custom reference object. Search criteria is based on nested properties. For a reference guide, let consider `Student` and `Subject` classes.

```
public class Student
{
    public String Name {get;set;}
    public List<Subject> Subjects {get;set;}
}

public Subject 
{
    public String Name {get;set;}
}
```

Not only I want to search Student by their names but the same search should also work with subject names as well. I've a single field where the text can be entered. For student search by their names, I've done:

```
FilteredList = Students.Where(s => s.Name.Contains(searchQuery));
```

Now, I also want to search students by the subject names but only want to show the matching results. A student can take many courses but a query of "Chemistry" should only show students who are taking this course but the rest of the courses they're taking should be ignored.

Basically my `FilteredList` is bound with `ListView` and `Subjects` list should only contain matching results. I'm keeping original source aside as `Students`. Any help implementing this search is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the LINQ function `Any` in this case. Something like this should give you the indented results :

```
FilteredList = Students.Where(s => s.Subjects.Any(subs => subs.Name.Contains(subjectSearchQuery))
```

If you want to use both filters at the same time, you can chain

```
FilteredList = Students.Where(s => s.Name.Contains(searchQuery))
    .Where(s => s.Subjects.Any(subs => subs.Name.Contains(subjectSearchQuery))
```

---

**EDIT : Seems like I understood the question wrong, here is what I think is the right answer (see the comments on this answer)**

In this you want to use `Select`, in a fashion like this :

```
FilteredList = Students.Where(s => s.Name.Contains(studentNameFilter))
    .Select(s => new Student() 
        { 
            Name = s.Name,
            subjects = s.Subjects.Where(sub => sub.Name.Contains(subjectNameFilter))
        });
```

This should give you the results you want.

Comment: I've already tried it. What I want is to filter subjects as well. This would only filter students. All the subjects within that student will still be there.

Comment: @UsmanKhalid So what you want is to return students all students that match the Student name filter, but in those students only return the subjects that match the subjects filter?

Comment: Yes, but in your last edit, it seems like only those subjects will be searched where student name is matched first. Let's say query is "Maths", will I get the students with subjects of Maths?

Comment: @UsmanKhalid Yeah, in the second, it'll match the name first, then the subjects. So say you search 'John' for the name and 'Maths' for the subject, it'll return all the students whose name contain 'John', and the student objects will only have subjects whose name contain 'Maths'. Basically this is done with 2 search strings (one for the student name and one for the subject name). If that's not what you want just let me know.